# How to make the resultset returned from oracle keeps its column aliases characters case

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, metadata, resultset

I am trying to querying some sql statment againest oracle database.

I am using `Java` `ResultSetMetaData` to get column alias names (through: `rsmd.getColumnLable()` )

The query looks like:

`select part_id partId, part_num partNumber from tbl;`

But the result set meta-data returns for me the aliases as `partid` and `partnumber` respectively ...

But I need to get the aliases in the same characters case the user choose, so I need to get it as `partId` and `partNumber` respectively.

How to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Column names and aliases are case insensitive by default, if you want to preserve case in an oracle statement you could quote the names like this:

```
select part_id "partId", part_num "partNumber" from tbl;
```

In my tests the column names where returned in uppercase when not using the quotes, so the behaviour might also depend on the version of the jdbc driver.

Comment: As a side note, it's worth pointing out that quoted aliases are not treated exactly like unquoted aliases.  For example, I can order by unquoted aliases but not quoted aliases.

Comment: @rimsky That is incorrect - you can order by any alias. `SELECT 123 AS "a" FROM DUAL ORDER BY "a"` will work and so will `SELECT 123 AS a FROM DUAL ORDER BY "A"`. Oracle is case sensitive - however the default behaviour is to convert any unquoted identifier to uppercase to abstract the case-sensitivity away from the user; quoted identifiers preserve the case. So the identifiers `a` (lower-case unquoted) and `"A"` (upper-case quoted) are the same identifier since the first will be converted to upper case and match the second.