# MyBatis custom TypeHandler not executed when put in <result> tag

Tags: java, mybatis, typehandler

I have a `<resultMap>` with custom `typeHandler` for one of the result properties:

```
<resultMap id="foo" type="hashmap">
    ... 
    <result property="SERVICES_XML" javaType="string" jdbcType="CLOB" typeHandler="com.foo.bar.OracleClobTypeHandler" />
    ...
</resultMap>
```

No matter which property I attach my handler to (I mean this is **not CLOB-specific issue**, tried with `VARCHAR`, too), the handler won't get called when I fetch results from database.

I have set breakpoints in all methods of my custom handler:

```
public class OracleClobTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<String> {

  @Override
  public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    log.debug("setParameter called");   <================ BREAKPOINT HERE
  }

  @Override
  public String getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
        throws SQLException {
    log.debug("getResult 2 called");    <================ BREAKPOINT HERE
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public String getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex)
        throws SQLException {
    log.debug("getResult 2 called");    <================ BREAKPOINT HERE
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public String getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
        throws SQLException {
    log.debug("getResult 3 called");    <================ BREAKPOINT HERE
    return "";
  }
}
```

Clearly none of the above methods is executed.

I've tried to put `<typeHandler javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="CLOB" handler="com.foo.bar.OracleClobTypeHandler"/>` in myBatis `<configuration>`, but this didn't work too.
Neither did anything else, including extending `TypeHandler<Object>` and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging a long, long while I have finally found the answer.

This seems to be a bug in myBatis.

In order to get your handlers to work for `<result>` elements, you have to specify `column` attribute explicitly **even if `property` attribute already matches column name and field name in bean**.
In my case, it looks like this:

```
 <result property="SERVICES_XML" column="SERVICES_XML" javaType="string" jdbcType="CLOB" typeHandler="com.foo.bar.OracleClobTypeHandler" />
```

Note that the above change will also cause handlers defined in `<configuration>` tag to work, so inline `typeHandler` may be no longer necessary - that was my case. I ended up with:

```
<configuration>
  <typeHandlers>
    <typeHandler javaType="java.lang.String" jdbcType="CLOB" handler="com.foo.bar.OracleClobTypeHandler"/>        
  </typeHandlers>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<result property="SERVICES_XML" column="SERVICES_XML" javaType="string" jdbcType="CLOB" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is 3 years old now, I'd rather bet the issue is related to the fact that Oracle '*uppercases*' columns name retrieved from result metadata, while case sensitive java object properties name usually respect camel case.

Then explicit column-property mapping is required unless you use quoted aliases in the SQL query.
[The question has been asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244142/how-to-make-the-resultset-returned-from-oracle-keeps-its-column-aliases-characte).
And unlike what is said in the latest comment, I have observed that ORDER BY quoted alias works.